# Solr sorting with special characters

Tags: solr

I want to be able to sort a field alphabetically which has native language chars, such as 'Ö', 'Ş' or 'Ç' (Turkish chars).

Related parts of my solr schema are as follows:

```
<field name="bookTitle" type="text_tr" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="bookTitleSort" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<copyField source="bookTitle" dest="bookTitleSort"/>
```

First, i tried to sort using `bookTitle asc`, but the results weren't in alphabetic order at all. Then i added a `string` field named `bookTitleSort`, and tried `bookTitleSort asc`. It worked fine except for the special chars. The ones that start with one of those chars are positioned at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ICUCollationKeyFilter`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ICUCollationKeyFilterFactory) to get usable sort orders that are locale aware. There's an example on the linked wiki page that shows how you can do this by having a `TextField` which has a `KeywordTokenizer` together with the `ICUCollationKeyFilter`:

```xml
<fieldType name="icu_sort_tr" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ICUCollationKeyFilterFactory" locale="tr" strength="primary"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

As far as I remember tr is the correct locale for Turkish, but feel free to double check that.

Comment: i used `CollationKeyFilterFactory` instead, because it didn't require any additional jars and worked fine for Turkish. also added `TurkishLowerCaseFilterFactory` filter. anyway, thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

'ICUCollationKeyFilterFactory' is depracated. You need to specifiy it as field type in schema like  :

```
<fieldType name="string_tr" class="solr.ICUCollationField"  locale="tr" strength="primary"  />
```

Since Collation libs are not included in default mode you need to add it in solrconfig. In solrconfig one has to add "solr-analysis-extras-*","icu4j-*","lucene-analyzers-icu-*". Be careful to add these libs only once. All the
jars will be loaded once and available to all cores. You can check your libs with solr verbose mode.

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-analysis-extras-.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lib" regex=".*\.jar"/> 
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

for starting solr in verbose mode solr one can start solr as `bin\solr.cmd start  -f -v`